# CSS property value that tells the browser the property value should not be changed

Tags: css

Is there such a thing?

Like

```
.el{
  background-image: don_change;
}
```

I have to define the property, but I don't want it to change in certain conditions (the element has a default value for that property in another .css file, which should be used).

If the value is a valid property like `url(image.jpg)`, then it should be applied

Comment: I'm afraid not. If you tell us what you are trying to do, we might be able to find you an alternative solution (e.g. what are the conditions?).

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too clear on what "If the value is a valid property" means... why would you be assigning invalid properties? WHy would you be assigning another background if you don't want to override the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work using the !important rule: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules

Answer (score 2):

`don_change` is a valid value in this case. Why? Because it's an invalid value.

If you have to specify a property name, but don't want it to influence the current styles, provide an invalid value. Invalid values will always be ignored by the browser.

When you want to disable a whole selector, add an invalid pseudo-selector to the set of selectors. An invalid pseudo-selector causes a whole rule set to be ignored (example: `:blabla, body{...}`).

If you want a style to persist, without possibly be changed by an inline style, or other style sheets, postfix your declaration by `!important`.

If you want to "reset" a style, however, the default (valid) value have to be specified. To find out the default value for a property, have a look at the [Mozilla's Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS). An easy method to quickly find the right page is by using Google, using `<keywords> mdn`, eg. `background-image css mdn`.

Comment: Makes sense: If the value isn't valid nothing will happen; but this is clearly a sign of some other problem.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I have tried to cover as much as possible of the topic. The OP is probably looking for the answer at paragraph 4 or 2.

Comment: Yeah I thought I understood OP's request, but now I'm not so sure. +1 for broad coverage :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to really do this, but you can come close:

```
.el{
    background-image: url(yourimage.jpg) !important;
}
```

The more specific the selector you use, the more priority the style will have, just in case you used a pretty specific selector in your override:

```
#my_content div.el {
    background-image: url(yourimage.jpg) !important;
}
```

However, using `!important` is not something you want to start doing as a habit. You should be able to find a way around the need for this.